# When a new data is published in power bi the previous data is erasing

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I have prepared chart using a data set in power bi and published, now I want to add another data set from another source, when I publish this data set, the previous data set is erasing off. I need both of them. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you publish a data set with the same name as an existing data set then it will overwrite the first data set.  The name of the data set is taken from the name of your Power BI Desktop (pbix) file that you are publishing. 
Try saving your Desktop file for the second chart under a different name and hopefully this will work.